# django não conecta ao banco mysql

Tags: mysql, django, servidor, conexão

estava fazendo esse projeto no linux Mint e tive que mudar para o windows e estou tendo alguns problemas pra configurar o ambiente.

ao rodar o comando

> $ python manage.py migrate

obtenho o seguinte erro:

> `(venv) C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica>python manage.py migrate
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
>       return Database.connect(**conn_params)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
>       super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
>   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)`
>
> `The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:`
>
> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
>       self.check()
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 59, in _run_checks
>       issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
>       issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 9, in check
>       issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
>       with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
>       return self._cursor()
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
>       self.ensure_connection()
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
>       raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
>       return Database.connect(**conn_params)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
>       return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Nee3p\PycharmProjects\clinica\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
>       super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)`

no `settings.py` tenho o seguinte:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

e meu arquivo `settings.ini` tem as informações corretas sobre o banco. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `settings.ini` ou `settings.py`?

Comment: `settings.ini` tem as informações para o python decouple, acesso elas ali pelo config(). o `settings.py` também está correto pois trouxe ele do backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é a nova versão do MySQL.

A partir da versão 8.04, o MySQL usa o caching_sha2_password como plugin de autenticação padrão, onde anteriormente mysql_native_password foi usado (o que causa problemas de compatibilidade com serviços mais antigos que esperam autenticação mysql_native_password).

Soluções:

Fazer o downgrade do servidor MySQL para uma versão abaixo dessa alteração ou altere o plug-in de autenticação (com base no usuário)

por exemplo, ao criar o usuário

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

se preciso, dê as permissões de acesso para o usuário.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

isso resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

settings.py
Não há tanto mistério,

pip install PyMySQL

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',# nome do driver
        'NAME': 'nome_db',
        'USER': 'usuario',
        'PASSWORD': 'senha',
        'HOST': 'localhost', # não obrigatorio, se desejar pode deixar ja especificado
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Para finalizar tem que criar o banco de dados com  mesmo nome definido no settings.
MySQL: [lib](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/)